# Ubuntu 22.04 running on VirtualBox keeps redirecting me to the password display

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, filesystem, password, 22.04

I also get a recurring warning stating that I have "Low Disk Space on Filesystem root". Is there a way to fix that issue? Is it a factor in my not being able to access the program? I have attempted solutions I have read just now, although they did not succeed. I tried:

1. Going into TTY3, typing `sudo mv .profile .profile.backup`, and then entering `sudo reboot`
2. This: `nano /etc/environment`
   Make the first line read:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:"
```

Press Ctrl+O to save the file.
Press Ctrl+X to exit.
Type `reboot` to restart your computer.

Edit #2: So the problem is that when I login in with my password, I will be able to access Ubuntu- but after about five seconds it returns to a black loading screen, and then back to the login display, and I can't stop it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and list the partitions of your virtual disk with their size. Does the problem occur after a fresh install or after some change to your previously running system? (What did you change?)

Comment: The title of the question has noting to do with the body of the question. Please edit and correct.

Comment: Updated the question- apologies for the prior vaugeness.

Comment: @A.S. Please provide the requested information. Without this it is difficult to suggest solutions.

Comment: @Bodo- Within the disk management panel on my Windows 10 os, it has a single Ubuntu partition- I think that is what you're referring to. It has 3.56 Gb of storage available, and is Healthy.  I made this VM a few days ago, so I don't think it counts as a fresh install. I haven't encountered this problem before. Sorry for the longish wait, have been inconvieneced